# Error connecting to node olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to run kafka using helm bitnami/kafka version 7.0.2
I am able to run all commands from inside the container but when i try to access the container using port forwarding or NodePort it's giving the error as mentioned:

```
[2022-04-13 13:07:51,461] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:984)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1128)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1388)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1331)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

on running *kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.49.2:30009 --list*

```
NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      3h54m
olfkafkademo                      NodePort    10.98.75.114    <none>        9092:30009/TCP               3h41m
olfkafkademo-headless             ClusterIP   None            <none>        9092/TCP                     3h41m
olfkafkademo-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.108.34.205   <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   3h41m
olfkafkademo-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   3h41m
```

```
(base) fa059037@aadarsh-ubuntu:~/Documents/intern/kafka/project$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
olfkafkademo-0             1/1     Running   1 (3h41m ago)   3h41m
olfkafkademo-zookeeper-0   1/1     Running   0               3h41m
```

```
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,460] INFO Opening socket connection to server olfkafkademo-zookeeper/10.108.34.205:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,463] INFO Socket connection established to olfkafkademo-zookeeper/10.108.34.205:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,490] INFO Session establishment complete on server olfkafkademo-zookeeper/10.108.34.205:2181, sessionid = 0x10000656a410000, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,494] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,778] INFO Cluster ID = _pi14GQ-RpKLqpG0HqVW9A (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,780] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /bitnami/kafka/data/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,821] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        authorizer.class.name = 
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = -1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        client.quota.callback.class = null
        compression.type = producer
        connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
        control.plane.listener.name = null
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
        delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
        delegation.token.master.key = null
        delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = false
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
        group.max.size = 2147483647
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name = 
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.3-IV1
        kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
        kafka.metrics.reporters = []
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = /bitnami/kafka/data
        log.flush.interval.messages = 10000
        log.flush.interval.ms = 1000
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.downconversion.enable = true
        log.message.format.version = 2.3-IV1
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = 1073741824
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
        max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
        message.max.bytes = 1000012
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        password.encoder.iterations = 4096
        password.encoder.key.length = 128
        password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
        password.encoder.old.secret = null
        password.encoder.secret = null
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.principal.mapping.rules = [DEFAULT]
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.connect = olfkafkademo-zookeeper
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,828] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        authorizer.class.name = 
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = -1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        client.quota.callback.class = null
        compression.type = producer
        connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
        control.plane.listener.name = null
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
        delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
        delegation.token.master.key = null
        delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = false
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
        group.max.size = 2147483647
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name = 
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.3-IV1
        kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
        kafka.metrics.reporters = []
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = /bitnami/kafka/data
        log.flush.interval.messages = 10000
        log.flush.interval.ms = 1000
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.downconversion.enable = true
        log.message.format.version = 2.3-IV1
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = 1073741824
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
        max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
        message.max.bytes = 1000012
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        password.encoder.iterations = 4096
        password.encoder.key.length = 128
        password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
        password.encoder.old.secret = null
        password.encoder.secret = null
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.principal.mapping.rules = [DEFAULT]
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.connect = olfkafkademo-zookeeper
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,846] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,846] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,847] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,867] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,871] INFO Logs loading complete in 4 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,880] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:28,881] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,146] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,213] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : EndPoint(null,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,215] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started 1 acceptor threads for data-plane (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,235] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,236] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,237] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,237] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-ElectPreferredLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,246] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,266] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1001 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,279] INFO Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/1001 is: 25,25,1649835269274,1649835269274,1,0,0,72058029612269568,294,0,25
 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,280] INFO Registered broker 1001 at path /brokers/ids/1001 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT)), czxid (broker epoch): 25 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,294] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /bitnami/kafka/data/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,332] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,336] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,336] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,346] INFO Successfully created /controller_epoch with initial epoch 0 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,348] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,349] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,351] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 2 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,360] INFO [ProducerId Manager 1001]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:1001,blockStartProducerId:0,blockEndProducerId:999) by writing to Zk with path version 1 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,418] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,420] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1001]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,420] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,531] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,540] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started data-plane processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,542] INFO Kafka version: 2.3.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,542] INFO Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,542] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1649835269540 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-04-13 07:34:29,544] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,478] INFO Creating topic first with configuration {} and initial partition assignment Map(0 -> ArrayBuffer(1001)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,495] INFO [KafkaApi-1001] Auto creation of topic first with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,570] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1001] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(first-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,637] INFO [Log partition=first-0, dir=/bitnami/kafka/data] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,641] INFO [Log partition=first-0, dir=/bitnami/kafka/data] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 42 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,642] INFO Created log for partition first-0 in /bitnami/kafka/data with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.downconversion.enable -> true, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 1000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, flush.messages -> 10000, message.format.version -> 2.3-IV1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.compaction.lag.ms -> 9223372036854775807, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> 1073741824, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, segment.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,643] INFO [Partition first-0 broker=1001] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition first-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,644] INFO Replica loaded for partition first-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2022-04-13 07:36:36,646] INFO [Partition first-0 broker=1001] first-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2022-04-13 07:44:29,349] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2022-04-13 07:54:29,349] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

The problem seems similiar to issue
[StackOverFlowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526530/bitnami-kafka-for-kibernetes-java-net-unknownhostexception-kafka-0-kafka-head)
On running dnslookup olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
It's getting resolved correctly as the same as above with an ip address.

The same issue pops up while running all of bitnami/kafka helm charts with versions below 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://olfkafkademo-0.olfkafkademo-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

This is the only address that clients will be able to resolve.

> try to access the container using port forwarding or NodePort

Your host machine will not be able to resolve the cluster's service DNS names. Either you need an Ingress or update the advertised listeners to include the `clusterIp` + `NodePort` *on each Kafka pod*. The headless service is only meant to be used *internally* to the cluster.

Seems like you didn't set `externalAccess.enabled=true`, which defaults to use port 9094 outside of the cluster and should not require any `kubectl port-forward`

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka#traffic-exposure-parameters

I'd suggest using an operator rather than just deploying a Helm chart - https://strimzi.io, and following it's own documentation for setting up external access

Comment: The externalAccess.enabled parameter is not available for bitnami/kafka version 7.0.2
Please see for reference on kafka version 7.0.2:
https://github.com/Aadarsh-Verma/kafka-7.0.2 
I am also sending my dry run results below:
https://paste.sh/8-3NqUvo#dhWEQSha-0_Q7swwGuCT7_Hq

Comment: 1) Why do you need to use that version, in particular? 2) Please read the logs at the very end that say "To connect to your Kafka server from outside the cluster execute the following commands ... " 3) You can add [an external service](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kafka/templates/svc-external-access.yaml) on your own

Comment: 1) I need to use kafka version 2.1.1 that is why I am sticking to helm 7.0.2.
2) I have read those logs and after port forwarding or configuring a NodePort I am getting the above mentioned error.
3) Also I am not getting NoBrokerException and I am also able to list the topics by using 
`import kafka
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['192.168.49.2:30009'])  # old kafka
print(consumer.topics())
`
But on running a producer I get the above exception and also on running 
`kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.49.2:30009 --list`

Comment: You're using Kafka 2.3 1, by the way. Look at the actual Docker image. Besides, any Kafka clients should be to work the exact same with higher Kafka versions, so I still don't understand the exact need for that version. Without seeing your new broker configs, showing code doesn't help me answer your question. If `192.168.49.2:30009` is not listed as an advertised listener, then it's just not going to work with forwarded ports or not.

Comment: ok Thanks for helping so far. So the real reason I am using kafka 2.1 or 2.3 is because I am not able to migrate my zookeeper data from version 2.3 to 2.4 . I am able to migrate the data from 2.1 to 2.3 or from 2.4 upto 3.1 but not between versions below 2.3 to versions above 2.4. If you can help me to migrate my kafka data from version 2.1 to 3.1(latest) then I can directly use the latest helm chart. Bascically for versions below 2.3 zookeeper does not have snapshot file and if we copy the zookeeper folder from 2.1 to 3.1 It gives an error that `No snapshot found, but there are log entries` .

Comment: My task is to migrate kafka on kubernetes but the version we are using is 2.1 and I can uprgade the kafka version but I need to retain the data on kafka. @OneCricketeer

Comment: You shouldn't need to upgrade Zookeeper to upgrade Kakfa. The Kafka documentation itself describes the upgrade process. I've never done it (or migrated a cluster) for Kubernetes. Regardless, that has nothing to do with exposing the listeners correctly

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you should be able to use the latest Helm chart and simply overwrite the Kafka docker image version in the values file

Comment: I thought of that too. The problem is even though I have mentioned the zookeeper image tag as 3.4.14-debian-9-r25 in my charts/zookeeper/Chart.yaml it is still running zookeeper 3.8.0 somehow. Please refer this https://github.com/Aadarsh-Verma/kafka-16.2  Altough everthing is working fine.
Zookeeper LOGS: https://paste.sh/vj5IK-n6#nk7ZLHsT4EwFpT2cd7PKUK4g

Comment: Where exactly are you overriding the image? You need to use values file, not Chart for that https://github.com/Aadarsh-Verma/kafka-16.2/blob/master/values.yaml#L1576

Comment: You could also just use your existing Zookeeper directly and not migrate it https://github.com/Aadarsh-Verma/kafka-16.2/blob/master/values.yaml#L1618

Comment: I have directly overridden it in the default values.yaml file. I also made changes in the Chart yaml file so that the version mentioned in values and Chart matches. It throws an error otherwise. my existing zookeeper is standalone I need to migrate to kubernetes on a different machine. 
Although I have been able to solve the problem migrating data between zookeeper older and newer version I just needed to add a default snapshot file.
but I still don't understand why my helm is running zookeeper 3.8 when I am using this image: 3.4.14-debian-9-r25.
There is a seperate values.yaml fileforzook.

Comment: I still think you need to edit the Kafka chart's value file to insert `zookeeper.image.tag` entry, not edit  charts/zookeeper/values.yaml since that file is never declared as a dependency

Comment: I have tried a couple of zookeeper versions such as 3.4.14-debian-9-r33,3.4.14-debian-9-r32.

It's giving me `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /opt/bitnami/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg file is missing`
I tried to run these zookeeper containers independently they work fine though.
Do I need to change any other property as well with the `zookeeper.image.tag`
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: any version above and including 3.5 is working.